# Python program doesn`t run in the background even after using & .. why?

Tags: python, python-daemon

I have a python program which curls to a machine and tries to run that file and if the file runs in 300secs its fine else it kills it.

```
import threading,datetime,signal,os
from threading import Thread
import logging,time
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import subprocess,os,errno
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

id = 1
p=Popen('hostname',stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
out,err=p.communicate()
global hostname
hostname=out.replace('\n','')
dir_path='/export/home/host/'+str(hostname)
curl_path='http://1.1.1.1:8080/host_exec/'+str(hostname)



def run_file(new_id,data):

    data=data.split(',')
    if len(data)>1:
        session=Popen(str(data[0])+' '+str(data[1]),shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)
    else:
        session=Popen(str(data[0]),shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print 'pid is ',session.pid

    stdout1=''
    stderr1=''

    while session.poll() is None:
        print 'sleeping'
        time.sleep(10)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        #Kill the process if its still running and timeout period is over ( max 20 secs )
        if (now - start).seconds > 10:
            os.kill(session.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
            killed_flag=1
            break;
        #This condition is checked to see if the process finished executing and doesn`t need to be killed - success
        elif session.poll() is not None:
            print 'Process has finished'
            stdout1=session.stdout.read()
            stderr1=session.stdout.read()
            break;
        #If timeout is still remaining - wait for it to finish or get killed
        else:
            print 'still executing'


    if killed_flag==1:
        stdout1=' THE SCRIPT COULDN`T COMPLETE EXECUTION ON HOSTNAME '+str(hostname)+' AS IT TOOK MORE THAN 5 MINUTES TO FINISH AND HENCE GOT KILLED : TRY RERUNNING IT OR RUN IT MANUALLY ON THE BOX'
        print stdout1



    ops=stdout1 + stderr1
    s = ServerProxy('http://paste/',allow_none=True)
    page_url=s.pastes.newPaste("text",ops,None)
    #print page_url
    #print stdout

    #Connect to db and update the table with the clob generated
    session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','abc/abc:1500'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    if flag==1:
       #print flag
       sql='update abc set temp_op = temp_op || \''+str(page_url)+',\', temp_db = temp_db || \''+str(hostname)+',\' where job_id=\''+str(new_id)+'\' ;'


    if flag==2:
        #print flag
        sql='update abc config set output=\''+str(page_url)+'\', job_status=\'Completed\' where job_id=\''+str(new_id)+'\' ;'

    session.stdin.write(sql)
    session.stdin.flush()
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
    #print stdout
    #print stderr



def do_this():
    print "Running with Current Id : ", id
    session=Popen('/export/home/curl '+str(curl_path)+'/filenames.txt',shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)
    stdout,stderr= session.communicate()

    files_in_dir=stdout.split(' ')
    if(len(files_in_dir)>1):
        print files_in_dir
        for file_name in files_in_dir:
            if file_name:
                file_list=file_name.split('_')
                new_id=file_list[1]

                if new_id>id:
                    session=Popen('/export/home/curl '+str(curl_path)+'/'+str(file_name),shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)
                    file_content,stderr= session.communicate()
                    t = Thread(target=run_file,args=(new_id,file_content,))
                    t.start()
                    global id
                    id = new_id
                else:
                    print 'No new file to process'
    else:
        print "EMPTY FOLDER"



while True:
    do_this()
    time.sleep(10)
```

But when I run it like

```
python abc.py &
```

It doesn`t run in the background. Why?

Also, When I do a CTRL+C or COMMAND+C to kill it .. it still keeps on running.

Comment: "It doesn`t run in the background" - what exactly do you mean by that?  Does it simply not run / start or does it ignore `&` and run in the foreground or what else happens?

Comment: Runs in the foreground ignoring & .. it runs as expected but not in the background.

Comment: The entire script, or only the executed `curl` commands?

Comment: The entire script coz of   while True:
    do_this()
    time.sleep(10)

Comment: The reason it keeps running when you ^C is because... it's running in the background! It's also printing to the terminal. Those two things aren't incompatible. A backgrounded process can't *read* from the terminal but it can write to it unless you redirect its output elsewhere.

Comment: But I have one other similar program with print statements and there it runs in the background when I use  &.   How can I redirect the output elsewhere?